# Terraform + AWS : Adding tag with dynamic values in the default_tags block of the provider

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using the terraform provider v5.21.0

I am trying to add a tag (whose value would be different on every terraform plan/apply) on every resources created by a provider by using the default_tags block.

my values.tfvars file is like this:

```yaml
tags = {
  Service               = "some_service"
  Project               = "some_project"
  Environment           = "prod"
}
```

my provider is setup like so:

```yaml
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-3"
  default_tags {
    tags = var.tags
  }
  ...
}
```

Everything works fine, all the resources get tagged using the tags described above.

Now, I want to add a tag called "LastTerraformApply" to all the resources.

If I modify my provider like this, no problems, ****only the "LastTerraformApply" tag gets updated**** even if I change the value of the tag between every "terraform plan/apply"

```yaml
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-3"
  default_tags {
    tags = merge(var.tags,
      {
        LastTerraformApply = "foo"
      }
    )
  }
  ...
}
```

Now, my issue/question is:

Instead of using a fixed string as the value of the "LastTerraformApply" tag, I would like to get the date and time of the last successful "terraform apply".

So I modified my provider like this:

```yaml
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-3"
  default_tags {
    tags = merge(var.tags,
      {
        LastTerraformApply = formatdate("DD-MM-YYYY@hh:mm Z", timestamp())
      }
    )
  }
  ...
}
```

But now, every time I run a plan/apply, terraform wants to destroy and recreate ALL the tags in ALL the resources. I was expecting that only the "LastTerraformApply" tag value would be updated, but no...

```yaml
# aws_mq_broker.broker will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_mq_broker" "broker" {
        id                         = "b-xxxxxxxxxx"
      ~ tags                       = {
          - "Environment"           = "prod" -> null
          - "LastTerraformApply"    = "16-10-2023@13:02 UTC" -> null
          - "Project"               = "some_project" -> null
          - "Service"               = "some_service" -> null
        }
      ~ tags_all                   = {
          - "Environment"           = "prod" -> null
          - "LastTerraformApply"    = "16-10-2023@13:02 UTC" -> null
          - "Project"               = "some_project" -> null
          - "Service"               = "some_service" -> null
        } -> (known after apply)
        # (14 unchanged attributes hidden)

        # (8 unchanged blocks hidden)
    }
```

I try to export the functions call to a local block, in case it would change something... it doesn't, same behaviour...

so as of now, my provider's code looks like this, but when I run it, all the tags in all the resources are destroyed and recreated....

```yaml
locals {
  now_datetime = formatdate("DD-MM-YYYY@hh:mm Z", timestamp())
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-3"
  default_tags {
    tags = merge(var.tags,
      {
        LastTerraformApply = local.now_datetime
      }
    )
  }
  ...
}
```

do you have any idea why it acts like that ?
And is there a way to get the expected behaviour ?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to add it to an output instead of a tag?

Comment: @MarkoE
Thanks for helping out :)
The whole idea is to be able to see directly from the AWS console when last 'terraform apply' has been ran on some resources. 
I don't work much with outputs. My understanding of them is that it will show some values every time I run a plan/apply. I would like to have this information visible to everyone in the team (hence via the AWS console) and not only to the Infra team (only team allowed to run terraform plan/apply)....

Does it make sense ?

Comment: You could maybe try with [ignore_tags](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#ignore_tags-configuration-block) argument for everything except the timestamp one.

Comment: @MarkoE
I did try that already, but still the same problem...
What I don't understand is why everything works if the value is a fixed string and it all goes south when the value is a call to some terraform functions.... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `timestamp` function is one of a small number of functions in Terraform that doesn't behave like a normal function. A normal function's result should depend only on the arguments passed to it, but `timestamp` breaks that rule by also depending on transient information from elsewhere: your computer's current wallclock time.

Since `timestamp` is defined as returning the (approximate) time that the resource instance was *applied*, its value is always unknown during planning: Terraform cannot predict during planning when and whether you will apply the plan. That means in turn that the provider cannot predict the final value of `tags_all` for any resource until the apply phase, and so it reports that the entire map will be "known after apply".

If you are using a recent version of Terraform you could potentially use [`plantimestamp`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/plantimestamp) instead, which returns the (approximate) time that a particular resource instance was *planned*, and can therefore be decided during the plan phase. As long as you apply the plan shortly after creating it, you will still have *roughly* the last time the configuration was applied.

---

However, I'd also caution that a behavior like this is not really what Terraform is designed to achieve.

Terraform is a "desired state" system, meaning that your configuration should typically describe a *stable state* that the remote system can be changed to match and will then match until next time you change the desired state. Using wallclock timestamps anywhere in your "desired state" means that your desired state is constantly changing and so Terraform will never be able to "converge", which is the term for when the desired state and the actual state match.

Convergence is a useful property because if you reach convergence and then see a change later you can assume that either the configuration has changed or the remote system has changed, and you can then decide how to respond. If your configuration *never* converges then it can be easy to miss unwanted changes in the constant noise of Terraform proposing to update the tags of every single object on every run.

In practice many remote systems tend to track last modified times for their objects automatically, without any special effort on your part or on Terraform's part. Those automatically-maintained timestamps are not part of the desired or actual state that Terraform cares about and therefore don't prevent "convergence", and you can also be sure that they will be accurate because the remote system maintains them automatically each time Terraform (or anything else) makes an API call to update the object.

Unfortunately according to [the `Broker` API docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/api-reference/brokers-broker-id.html#brokers-broker-id-schemas) it appears that at the time of writing a "broker" object only tracks when it was created (the `created` property) and not when it was most recently updated. Perhaps AWS would be interested in learning about your use-case for tracking the last updated time for these objects so they could consider adding an automatically-maintained last updated time as part of the Amazon MQ system.

Answer (score 0):

Comments are too short for what I want to write :)

To get the full explanation and the function to use, please check the accepted answer by Martin Atkins.

---

Hi Martin,

thanks for your very clear and well explained answer.

1st of, I overlooked the plantimestamp function when I looked at the documentation and, in short, it fixes my problem....

thank you so much for that :)

For anyone landing on this question/answer, now my provider's code looks like this:

```yaml
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-3"
  default_tags {
    tags = merge(var.tags,
      {
        LastTerraformApply = formatdate("DD-MM-YYYY@hh:mm ZZZ+02", timeadd(plantimestamp(),"02h"))
      }
    )
  }
}
```

with some slight modifications to get the date/time exactly as I wanted it (UTC+2h).

now my plan only shows, as expected, the modification of the "LasTerraformApply" :

```yaml
  # aws_mq_broker.broker will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_mq_broker" "broker" {
        id                         = "b-xxxxx"
        tags                       = {}
      ~ tags_all                   = {
          + "LastTerraformApply"    = "17-10-2023@18:06 UTC+02"
            # (8 unchanged elements hidden)
        }
        # (14 unchanged attributes hidden)

        # (8 unchanged blocks hidden)
    }
```

but as you correctly point out, using this approach brings a lot of noise to the terraform plan.
I accept this trade off since having the information of exactly when a terraform configuration has been applied last is more important to us than some noise in the plan.

The other approach you were proposing couldn't solve the problem I am trying to address since, as you've found out, not all resources have a "last configuration" attribute that can be leverage.
That is why I am trying to found a more reliable and applicable solution to the maximum amount of resources and since, in AWS at least, nearly all resources accept tags, it is, in my opinion, the best solution.

As of now, thanks to you, this is the best I can think of and it actually does the job pretty well.

The other solution would be to summit a "Feature Request" to the terraform github repo to ask if creating a function that could be used to address this use case and that wouldn't be spotted by 'terraform plan/apply' as a change (hence not beinbg displayed in the plan) would be a something they would be willing to look into.
But as you said, since terraform is a "desired state" system, I am not sure that having some function that would change the state silently, would be a something desirable.